# Error on camera image capture with intent

Tags: android, camera

**Edited:** I am getting errors on android camera image capture using intent. I am actually trying to capture a photo via camera and display the captured image on an ImageView. Below are the errors I get.

```
Bitmap cannot be resolved to a type
mImageView cannot be resolved
```

Could anyone please help me on it. I've produced my code below.

```
package com.example.imageupload;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    /**********  File Path *************/
    final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
    final String uploadFileName = "";

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Bundle extras =data.getExtras();
                Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What kind of errors?

Comment: It's just me or `onActivityResult` is inside `dispatchTakePictureIntent`?

Comment: move `onActivityResult` out from `dispatchTakePictureIntent` method.

Comment: 1. void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult

2. Bitmap cannot be resolved to a type

3. mImageView cannot be resolved

Comment: @codePG:
 thanks codePG.... the onActivityResult error has gone now. But the other two errors exist still. As I said,
2. Bitmap cannot be resolved to a type
3. mImageView cannot be resolved

Comment: @vinaysam Make sure you have declared and initialized your `mImageView` in your `onCreate` method.

Comment: Thanks all.... now that the errors are off....
I declared mImageView and the errors are gone...
Thanks again...

Comment: Hope `Mr. DownVoter` may take the downVote back. I've now edited the question. It was actually a mistake. U could've either edited or suggested a question edit instead of DownVoting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks guys for your help on my doubts regarding the coding on developing a camera app. And that I've done coding successfully. Here is the error less coding I've done. (I'm sorry, I'm new. Sorry if the code is too vague or something)...

```js
//MainActivity.java//
package com.example.imageupload;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
 TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;
        
    String upLoadServerUri = null;
     
    /**********  File Path *************/
    final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/";
    final String uploadFileName = "";
    
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
     Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null) {
      startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     }
     
      }
    
    @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
   Bundle extras =data.getExtras();
   Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
   ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(this);
   mImageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
   
     }
     
    }
```